# Вывод массива PHP

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [2] => 111
        [3] => 222
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [2] => 333
        [3] => 444
    )
)
```

Как его вывести, чтобы получилось так:

111 222

333 444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($array as $val)
{
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach($val as $v)
  {
    echo "<td>$v</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

или(если не html)

```
foreach($array as $val)
{
  foreach($val as $v)
  {
    echo "$v ";
  }
  echo "\r\n";
}
```